# MySQL - Select Rows in a Certain Sequence

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to build a people directory like LinkedIn has:

http://www.linkedin.com/directory/people-a

I don't want to fetch all the rows with `name` field starting with `a` and build the link list like LinkedIn. Is there any way in MySQL so I can only fetch rows in this sequence:

1st, 100th,101st,200th,201st,300th,301st,400th,401st, Last

That means I am trying to get two consecutive rows after a certain `gap` including the first and last item. The ids are not in nice uniformly increasing order, so I can't use this [answser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026377/mysql-how-to-select-a-range-of-ids-at-set-intervals). Any help or hint is appreciated.

---

Say my query `SELECT * FROM`businesses`where name like 'a%' order by name` returns id like this:

1,3,5,6,8, 9,12,33,45,66,77,88,100,103,120,133,155,166,177,178,198

Above is if I want to get all the rows. But what I want is to get only the items after a certain distance. For example if I want to pick after every 5 items:

1,9,12, 88,100,166,177,198

So skip 4 items and take next two. Is that even possible in mysql?

Comment: Do you need any more information to improve this question?

Comment: For future visitors: please visit this thread http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106079/sql-select-rows-in-a-certain-order/106105 dba seems better than SO for these kind of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can order by whatever you want
create some function that gets a number and return 0,1 (all the numbers you specified will be 0 for example), then you need to pass the rank of the row to your function.

example

```
select first_name,rank
  from (
         SELECT first_name,
                @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
           FROM person p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ) x
 order by myfunc(x.rank);
```

myfunc being the function you wrote

if you want to only get those rows, not just sort by it and get them first you can do the following :

```
select first_name,rank
 from (
        SELECT first_name,
               @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
          FROM person p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ) x
 where rank in (1,100,101,102...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Problem is I don't know the numbers beforehand. They can vary depending on my query. But all I know is between each number there are 100 more items that I want skip.

Comment: I ended up using something close to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can select a range with the limit clause

```
SELECT ...... LIMIT 0,99
```

This will give the first 100 records

```
SELECT ...... LIMIT 100,199
```

will give the next & so on

Comment: Thanks, I'm not trying to select range of items. But only items that are certain distant apart.